# Como definir uma página padrão?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Baixei um projeto, que quando vou rodar da isso:
O servidor Web está configurado para não listar o conteúdo deste diretório.

sou novo nesse ambiente, o que tenho que configurar?

Obs: Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não consegue aceder a uma página .aspx específica? A página chamada automaticamente deverá chamar-se default.aspx.

Comment: o prblema era exatamente esse, obrigado